# How to notate this kind of function?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

I have a function $f$ whose domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and range is a set of another functions. The domain of $f(n)$ is $\mathbb{N}_0 \cap [0,\frac{n}{2})$ and its codomain is $\mathbb{Z}$. How can I notate the codomain of $f$?

Comment: Can you define antidomain? I haven't heard that before.

Comment: @dbx Basically, any superset of the range.

Comment: @dbx Oh, sorry. "Codomain" is the word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either

$$f:\Bbb N\to\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}{^{n}\Bbb Z}$$

or

$$f:\Bbb N\to\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\Bbb Z^{n}\;,$$

where $n=\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

In general ${{^A}B}$ and $B^A$ are used for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$.

The fact that the domain of $f(n)$ is a function of $n$ pretty much has to be specified separately.

Comment: Doesn't what you've written declare that each $f(n)$ has domain $\mathbb N_0$?

Comment: @MarkS.: You’re right; that was dreadfully sloppy, and I’ve corrected it.